# IndexOutOfBoundsException when selecting tab in Tablayout

Tags: java, android

I get `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error when i want selecting the tab in the `TabLayout` :
This is the initTablayout function , that called in the `onCreate` method:

```
       //======================================== Init Tablayout and view pager
            private void initTabLayout() {
                mainActivityViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager_main_activity);


                mainActivityTabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_layout_main_activity);
                TabLayout.Tab tab = mainActivityTabLayout.getTabAt(1);
                tab.select();

                FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                MainActivityPagerAdapter adapter = new MainActivityPagerAdapter(manager);
                mainActivityViewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
                mainActivityTabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mainActivityViewPager);
                mainActivityViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(mainActivityTabLayout));
                mainActivityTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);
            }
```

I got this error where i choose index of selected tab on the `getTabAt(1)` method , i have three tab on the `PagerAdapter` class :

```
public class MainActivityPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        //============================================ Constructor

        public MainActivityPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        //============================================ GetItem Method ()
        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            Fragment frag = null;
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    frag = new Fragment_one();
                    break;
                case 1:
                    frag = new Fragment_two();
                    break;
                case 2:
                    frag = new Fragment_three();
                    break;

            }
            return frag;
        }

        //============================================= GetCount Method ()
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

        //============================================= GetPageTitle

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            String title = "";
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    title = "اول ";
                    break;
                case 1:
                    title = "دوم ";
                    break;
                case 2:
                    title = "سوم ";
                    break;

            }

            return title;
        }
    }
```

Complete error is :

```
 java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
```

Comment: try to get tab below `mainActivityTabLayout.setTabsFromPagerAdapter(adapter);`

Comment: iIt say : java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0

Comment: why are you using a deprecated API...

Comment: you haven't added tab to view pager

Comment: @Rohan and which is the deprecated API? got me curious.

Comment: me too curious@iBobb

Comment: Oops, my bad...I thought OP was using the `ActionBar.Tab` class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem like you forget to addTab to your `mainActivityTabLayout` so your `TabLayout` will have 0 item. Therefore, you got `IndexOutOfBoundsException` when you access to tab1

```
mainActivityTabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("1"));
mainActivityTabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("2"));
mainActivityTabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("3"));
```

Comment: my main purpose is selecting last tab in my tablayout , but i don't know how , your sulution solved index error but , last tab not select . anyway thanks for your sulution

Answer (score -1):

Select tab3

Do following :

```
mainActivityTabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("3"),true);
```